# CSS 3 Image Shadows

Tags: css, image

Can anyone here tell my what the most effective and simple way to use shadowing for images (instead of div boxes) in CSS is? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if you are not happy with css shadowing you can create individual image with shadow and insert. but this accept if you are unable to style using css.

Answer (score 1):

Add a style to your image like :

```
#yourimg {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #333;
}
```

Browser support is very well [using](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow)

Answer (score 1):

In generally,

```
box-shadow: Xpx Ypx Bpx Lpx #color;

Xpx = x-axis horizontal offset
Ypx = y-axis vertical offset
Bpx = blur effect
Lpx = spread length
#color = color
```

this is the solution for you.

```
box-shadow:2px 2px 3px black;
```

**if you are using internal style**

```
<img src="" style="box-shadow:2px 2px 3px black;"/>
```

**if you are using external style**,
in your html

```
<img src="" class="shadow"/>
```

then in your css

```
.shadow{
  box-shadow:2px 2px 3px black;
}
```